# Keras select random branch

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I want to randomly choose between two branches of a network during training and execution. I want to be able to do many of these random choices.

My motivation is to explore the similarities between the swappable parts of the network after the whole system converges. Eventually, I'd like my system to look like this:
[image]

I've tried this approach, but it appears there's a problem with the condition of the `K.switch` statement:

```
# can ignore details of this function
def make_first_half(input):
    m = Conv2D(16,
               kernel_size=(3, 3),
               activation='relu',
               input_shape=input_shape)(input)
    m = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(m)
    m = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(m)
    m = Flatten()(m)
    return m

# can ignore details of this function
def make_second_half(input):
    m = Dense(32, activation='relu')(input)
    m = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(m)
    return m


input = Input(shape=input_shape)

a1 = make_first_half(input)
a2 = make_first_half(input)

a = K.switch(
    lambda x: 1 == random.randint(0, 1),
    a1, a2)

prediction = make_second_half(a)
```

I think I understand what's wrong: the condition of the `K.switch` should be a tensor instead of a function returning a boolean. However, I'm unsure how I can make a tensor that is random for everytime it gets to that point. That is, I don't want to randomly choose a path at the very start, then take that path every time, ignoring the other.

I'd also prefer to run just one, not multiple, training sessions (i.e., only one `Model` statement, one `compile` statement, and one `fit` statement).

I'm using the TensorFlow backend.

It's totally possible I'm thinking about it wrong. Please explain how I can achieve this random branching.

Comment: Are you sure you need this random branching? Couldn't you just create a model with two outputs?

Comment: That's a great idea, but I don't understand how I achieve that with Keras's API. I'm adding some clarification about my goal that might inform you...

Comment: I looked at you graph and it seems to me that what you are trying to do is totally against the sense of neural networks. I think the best idea would be to explore the whole 3*3*3 = 27 possibilities separately (separate models, separate trainings) and choose the one that fits you best!

Comment: In almost all cases you'd be right! Not trying to make a high-performing network. I'm doing some research into these swappable parts: do they converge and how are they similar/different?